# Variable declarations, using libuv

Tags: c, libuv

I am trying to learn how to use libuv. I am on a mac OS X and have the library downloaded and installed. I can compile and run small test programs one only starts a callback loop and then exits since there are no watchers, the other creates an idle watcher and exits when the time runs out.

I have been trying to go through the samples for the file io and have been running into problems. The function prototype for the function to obtain a file descriptor is:

```
 int uv_fs_open(uv_loop_t* loop, 
                uv_fs_t* req,      // second argument
                const char* path, 
                int flags, 
                int mode, 
                uv_fs_cb cb)
```

I have cut the sample code down to the min that will still have the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <uv.h>

uv_fs_t open_req;

void on_open(uv_fs_t);
void on_read(uv_fs_t);
void on_write(uv_fs_t);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    uv_fs_open(uv_default_loop(), &open_req, argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0, on_open); 
    uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_DEFAULT); 
    return 0;
}


void on_open(uv_fs_t *req) {
    if (req->result != -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "function called \n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "error opening file: %d\n", req->errorno);
    }
    uv_fs_req_cleanup(req);
}
```

My declaration of open_req is exactly like the declaration of close_req which appears in the complete code sample and doesn't produce and error. I added the declaration for open_req because the compiler was giving me a "‘open_req’ was not declared in this scope" error. When I added the declaration it changed the error to "invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(uv_fs_t)’ to ‘void (*)(uv_fs_t*)’". I get the same error rather the declaration is inside main or not. If I change the declaration to a pointer declaration

```
uv_fs_t* open_req;
```

then I get the error:

```
cannot convert uv_fs_t** to uv_fs_t* for argument ‘2’ to 
int uv_fs_open(uv_loop_t*, uv_fs_t*, const char*, int, int, void (*)(uv_fs_t*))
```

I am trying to go through the actual libuv code to see if I can figure it out but the code is huge, I am using the "An Introduction to libuv" found here: http://nikhilm.github.com/uvbook/ and that is where the sample code came from.

Is there any other source of sample code that I can use to try and figure out this library? Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong in my declaration? I am not sure where to look for clarification or examples on how to use libuv.

Edit update
In the libuv code, in the uv.h file. I find

```
typedef struct uv_fs_s uv_fs_t;
```

one of the things I have been looking for in the code is where this struct is actually defined. I have searched using google for typedef and learned a bit about how typedef is used to make the name so that you don't have to type struct every time that you want to declare an instance of the struct. Though some people seem to think it is a terrible practice and others think it is great. Part of what I removed to get a minimum sample as another declaration of a type us_fs_t called close_req. I copied the format for my declaration directly from that one.

I will see what I can find about pointers to functions, I am only vaguely familiar with them and it at least gives me somewhere to start looking.

I have found the function definition for uv_fs_open.

```
int uv_fs_open(uv_loop_t* loop,
               uv_fs_t* req,
               const char* path,
               int flags,
               int mode,
               uv_fs_cb cb) {
  INIT(OPEN);
  PATH;
  req->flags = flags;
  req->mode = mode;
  POST;
}
```

Comment: are you showing complete code, as far as i can thing the error is possible if you declare any local variable like `uv_fs_t* open_req;` that overrides globally declared variable `uv_fs_t open_req;` other wise no chance.

Comment: The sample code is actually in four pieces in the Intro to libuv tutorial. Main, on_open, and on_read, and on_write. They drive each other in a loop. I am wondering if there is something else that should be included but haven't been able to see anything else in searching. I took the meat out of the on_open function so it wouldn't call the other functions and I could figure out the basic variable problem before adding in other stuff.

Comment: The problem boils down to the issue that it looks like `open_req` should be a function (or a function pointer), but you do not show how it is initialized. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: After a closer look, I don't believe that `open_req` caused the original error. I have edited my answer with a speculative suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state that the prototype for the function `uv_fs_open` is

```
int uv_fs_open(uv_loop_t* loop, 
               uv_fs_t* req, 
               const char* path, 
               int flags, 
               int mode, 
               uv_fs_cb cb)
```

Note that the type of the second argument is `uv_fs_t*`. So when you declare `open-rec` as

```
uv_fs_t open_req;
```

And then call `uv_fs_open()` with

```
uv_fs_open(uv_default_loop(), &open_req, argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0, on_open);
```

the second argument (`&open_req`) takes the address of `open_req` and creates the required pointer. This *should* work just fine. However, from your original error message, I think you did not post all of the relevant code. Let's look at this error message:

> invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(uv_fs_t)’ to ‘void (*)(uv_fs_t*)’

This states that the compiler expects a pointer to a function which returns void and takes a single parameter which is a pointer to a `uv_fs_t`. On the other hand, you are providing a pointer to a function which returns void and takes a single parameter of type `uv_fs_t` (i.e. not a *pointer* to `uv_fs_t`).

This suggests that `open_req` is a function (or a pointer to a function). In order to help you further, please edit your original question with the declaration of this function as well as how you initialize the `open_req` variable if it is a pointer to a function rather than the name of the function itself.

**Edit:**

After a second look at your question, `open_req` most likely doesn't cause the original error. You should change your code back to the way it was originally.

On the other hand, `on_open` very likely causes the problem. You declare this function with the prototype

```
void on_open(uv_fs_t);
```

but the first line of the definition is

```
void on_open(uv_fs_t *req)
```

Remove the `*` from the first line of the function definition and see what happens.

Comment: I don't have the option to up vote answers yet or I would do so, and I will when I get enough rep to have the ability. I do have one point of clarification though. Looking at the full length prototype and the definition I see the * in both, I am not understanding what you are saying. Both are directly from the code that created the library not code I wrote. I think my problem is more like how I am using it than how they wrote it.

Comment: @EdwardGoodson In the code you posted here, the prototype of `on_open()` doesn't have a * but the definition does. Are these the prototype and definition you are talking about? If this differs from the code you are actually compiling, please update your question. Also, when you figure out the solution to your problem, you can accept my answer (if it helped) by clicking the check mark no matter how much rep you have.

Comment: I think I see what you are talking about now.

Comment: @Edward To clarify, lines 4 and 12 are different. They *must* be the same.

Comment: Lines 4 and 12 in your answer?

Comment: I was looking in the complete wrong place. Got my mind in a rut and couldn't see. the kind of thing that makes one feel dumb. Thank you so much for your help.